# Trying to override _beforeSave method and Magento calling both custom method and core method as well

Tags: magento-1.7

All I am trying to override the **_beforeSave()** method in resource model **Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer**.

There is no problem in overriding as I can get the call to my **custom _beforeSave** method in my Custom Class.

Config for my custom Class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abc_Customer>
    </modules>

    <global>       
        <models>
            <cust>
                <class>Abc_Customer_Model</class>   
                <resourceModel>cust_resource</resourceModel> 
            </cust>  
            <cust_resource>
                <class>Abc_Customer_Model_Resource</class>
            </cust_resource>
            <customer_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>Abc_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>                
            </customer_resource>    
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

After that I have created the **Abc_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer** class, copied the **_beforeSave** method from the core class and changed according to need.

But the problem is now that magento is calling both of the methods.

How can I stop this behaviour and just let only my custom method to run?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not actually a problem.
If you copied the original `_beforeSave()` then this line is in there:

```
parent::_beforeSave($customer);
```

This the original class this was used to call the method in the parent class: `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave()`.
This is what basically happens to your new class. The method `_beforeSave()` from the parent is called from your method. Only now the parent of your class is `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer`, so the original method is called.
What you need it something like `parent::parent::_beforeSave($customer)` which in PHP can be done by using the `grandparent_class_name::method`

```
parent::_beforeSave($customer)
```

with

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave($customer)`

Comment: PHP actually does support doing parent::parent by using the parent class name::method, thus replacing the 'parent::_beforeSave($customer) with Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave($customer)' will work to call the grandparent class function.

This has (at times) caused quite a debate in our office, as some claim this breaks OOP conventions ;)

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

"...allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class."

ref: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42016

Comment: @ProxiBlue OK....so I learn new thing every day :). I did not know that. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was wondering, is there could be any other way to do the same like this could get confusing for other people to understand.

Comment: @RIK. Well...everything can be confusing to some people. This is the way magento works for extending classes.

Comment: @Marius - Please note that as of PHP5.4, calling the parent::parent method statically as described now throws a strict warning. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768576/how-can-i-solve-non-static-method-xxxxxx-should-not-be-called-statically-in (to notice is that the PHP docs for the :: does not reflect this)

Answer (score 2):

You need to know where the second call is originating from.

It could be that something else is extending that core class, and also doing a save, thus making the second call.

If you are using a debugger, then place a breakpoint on the core _beforeSave() and check the stack trace to see where the call is originating from. You'd be interested in the calling class instance name.

If no debugger, use PHP [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get a trace of the execution to that call.

Once you can find where it originates from, then you'd most likely solve the issue.